# Symfony method's result in Twig template

Tags: php, symfony, twig

question is there - How to get results from the service in a Twig template?

Versions:
Symfony 6.1.12
PHP 8.1.6

I have the class Navigation, that returns Navigation array with the method getNavigation():

```
namespace App\Service;

use Symfony\Component\Routing\RouterInterface;

class Navigation
{
    private RouterInterface $router;
    private array $navigation = [];

    public function __construct(RouterInterface $router)
    {
        $this->router = $router;

        $this->setNavigation();
    }

    public function setNavigation(array $nav = []): void
    {
        $this->navigation = $nav;

        if(empty($this->navigation)) {
            $this->navigation = [
                'Home' => $this->router->generate('homepage'),
                'Products' => $this->router->generate('products'),
                'Contacts' => $this->router->generate('contacts'),
            ];
        }
    }
    
    public function getNavigation(): Array
    {
        return $this->navigation;
    }
}
```

Now it works by calling the class in each Controller (for example:)

```
public function __construct(Navigation $navigation)
    {
        $this->navigation = $navigation;
    }

// #[Route('/', name: 'homepage')]
    public function index(): Response
    {
        return $this->render('home/index.html.twig', [
            'navigation' => $this->navigation->getNavigation(),
        ]);
    }
```

Is it possible to get access from this service in a `nav.html.twig template` without calling this instance everytime?

I've tried to save the service in services.yaml by

```
services:
    app.navigation:
        class: App\Service\Navigation
```

and then get the access by `{{ app.navigation.getNavigation() }}` in twig, but it does'nt work.

Thanks in advance for answers.

Comment: You are pretty close.  Take a look at [twig globals](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#global-variables).

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways.

1. Twig Global. You can set your service as a twig global. If you call that service every page that will be good.
   [Symfony Twig Globals](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#global-variables)

> ```
> config/packages/twig.yaml
> twig:
> #...
> globals:
>     #the value is the service's id
>     navigation: '@App\\Service\\Navigation' // maybe service id app.navigation
> ```

And use that in twig:

> ```
>     {{navigation.getNavigation()}}
> ```

2. Twig Runtime. You can create a runtime class and twig extension class. Then call that function in your twig lazily
   [Symfony lazy twig extension](https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#creating-lazy-loaded-twig-extensions)

And I think you should change service define method. Take a look [Symfony services](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html)

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion the best way is to write a twig extension and call the service class

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templates.html#writing-a-twig-extension

```
// App/Twig/NavigationExtension.php
namespace App\Twig;

use App\Service\Navigation;
use Twig\Extension\AbstractExtension;
use Twig\TwigFunction;

class NavigationExtension extends AbstractExtension
{
    private $navigation;

    public function __construct(Navigation $navigation)
    {
        $this->navigation = $navigation;
    }

    public function getFilters(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getFunctions(): array
    {
        return [
            new TwigFunction('getNavigation', [$this, 'getNavigation']),
        ];
    }

    public function getNavigation()
    {
        return $this->navigation->getNavigation();
    }
}
```

in a twig template

```
// templates/somewhere.html.twig
<div>
    {{ getNavigation() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you defined a function called **printtext()**  in **src\Service\MyFunctions.php**

Define your functions service file in **twig.yaml**

```
twig:
    file_name_pattern: '*.twig'
    globals:
         myfunc: '@App\Service\MyFunctions'
```

Call your function in **yourpage.html.twig**

```
{{  myfunc.printtext()}}
```